# How to obtain the last number different to zero in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, zero

I have for example this array:

```
double array1[] = {2.3, 5.0, 4.7, 8.2, 1.8, 9.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

And I want to find the last number of the array different to 0. In this case, my output should be:  9.0

My code is:

```
double array1[] = {2.3, 5.0, 4.7, 8.2, 1.8, 9.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
double array2[] = array1.length;
double num;

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    array2[i] = array1[i];
    if(array2 != 0){
        num = array[i-1];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I need to highlight that the size of the array1 is always the same. But the non-zero numbers can change, in any case, all the zeros will be at the end of the array always.

I need also have array2, obtained by array1.

Furthermore, all the numbers are always positive.

Comment: What's `'` in your array

Comment: Your array gives me an error (in eclipse) `invalid character constant`.  I wouldn't expect the posted code to be executable.

Comment: I'm guessing he has some Locale differences in his JDK that's interpretting floating point numbers with a ' instead of a .

Comment: I am sorry, it is a mistake, the original code has difficult names and I have done the same code simplified in order to be concise in my question so I have done the code by hand in this post. The correct array sintaxis is: double array1[] = {2.3, 5.0, 4.7, 8.2, 1.8, 9.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Comment: Post your correction as an edit to the Question, not as a Comment.

Comment: Note that the question name and the description are inconsistent.  Do you want the first item in the array that is not 0 or the last item in the array that is not 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using a loop and the ternary operator (`a ? b : c` says if a is true return `b`, else return `c`)

```
double array1[] = {2.3, 5.0, 4.7, 8.2, 1.8, 9.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

- initialize last to 0.
- iterate over array
- if current value (i) == 0, return last.
- else return i

```
double last = 0;
for(double i : array1) {
    last = i == 0 ? last : i;
}
System.out.println(last);
```

prints
9.0

Answer (score 3):

You need to start at the end of the array, not the beginning:

```
public static double getLastNonZero(double [] data) throws Exception {
    for (int i = data.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (data[i] != 0) {
            return data[i];
        }
    }
    
    throw new Exception("No value found");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double array1[] = {2.3, 5.0, 4.7, 8.2, 1.8, 9.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    try {
        System.out.println(getLastNonZero(array1));         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't.  -1 might be a valid value in the list. The original message doesn't say the list will always have positive values. We have no context for what the value represent.

Comment: Or, perhaps the very best result would be an [`OptionalDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html).

Comment: That has possibility.  I'm used to old school java and forget about many of the newer features.

Comment: This program returns me the first number: 2.3, and I need the last number: 9.0

Comment: Quite frankly, this is a better solution than mine (the one you accepted).  It works fine since it is iterating from the last value to the first value in the array and returns the  first non-zero number encountered.  So it doesn't have to search the entire array. You must have done something wrong.  You should accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
Arrays
    .stream( myArray ) 
    .filter( d -> d != 0 )
    .reduce( ( first , second ) -> second   )
```

## `DoubleStream`

Not necessarily the best approach, but we can use streams. Specifically, `DoubleStream`.

After producing the stream from our array, filter out zero values. Then retrieve the last element by calling `reduce`.

We end up with an [`OptionalDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html) object that either contains our resulting `double` primitive or is empty which means no matches were found in our original array.

```
double[] doubles = { 1.0d , 2.2d , 3.3d, 0d , 0d } ;
OptionalDouble result = 
    Arrays
    .stream( doubles ) 
    .filter( d -> d != 0 )
    .reduce( ( first , second ) -> second   ) 
;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( result ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/urEAT4).

> OptionalDouble[3.3]